# Expected number of dice rolls to see each number twice

Tags: probability, dice

In one version of this question, it is required to compute expected number of rolls to see each side of a dice. In that case, the answer is

$$\frac{6}{6}+\frac{6}{5}+\frac{6}{4}+\frac{6}{3}+\frac{6}{2}+\frac{6}{1}=14.7.$$

I wonder whether the requirement to see each side twice is equivalent to to seeing each side of 12-sided dice at least once, i.e.,

$$\frac{12}{12}+\frac{12}{11}+\frac{12}{10}+\frac{12}{9}+\frac{12}{8}+\frac{12}{7}+\frac{12}{6}+\frac{12}{5}+\frac{12}{4}+\frac{12}{3}+\frac{12}{2}+\frac{12}{1}\approx37.24.$$

Comment: Doesn't work for a $1-$sided die versus a $2-$sided die.  You could try $2-$ versus $4-$ if you liked.

Comment: So your problem is equivalent to a special case of the problem in the duplicate, with $6$ choices and coupons needed $2$ for each.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel thank you

Comment: In particular the answer to your specific question is $\frac{390968681}{16200000}=24.13386\dots$